# Why is the name "Harkonnen" used on Seras' cannon in Hellsing?

Tags: anime, hellsing-anime

After reading an interesting post on the "anti-midian" meaning of Seras' battle rifle/cannon thing, I would like to know what the motif of Vladimir Harkonnen from the "Dune" series has to do with her cannon?

[image]

Let me give you an example, Alucard's awesome pistol "The Jackal" (SPOILER ALERT) symbolizes Walter's future betrayal of Alucard because, in the Fred Forsyth book "The Day of The Jackal", the character The Jackal kills everyone who helped him make his forged documents and weapon as a way of covering his tracks as he tries to kill Charles De Gaulle. In the dream sequence where this motif is introduced The Jackal comments "Never trust the man who makes your own weapon." which foreshadows Walter's betrayal.

So since Seras has two huge cannons that bear the Vladimir Harkonnen name and she even talks to Harkonnen in a trippy dream sequence, what kind of symbolism or motif does Harkonnen have in relation to the Hellsing universe?

Comment: There is already anime site : http://anime.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Euphoric That doesn't mean anime is off topic here. http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/627/1027

Comment: @Keen But OP might have better chance of getting better answer on more specialized site.

Comment: Sometimes names don't have to signify anything in-world - remember Loveless and Sister Ray in FF7.

Comment: Wait, there's an anime stackexchange? Sorry, I'm new here and didn't know. Hell yeah! This site is alright by me! Thanks for the info!

Comment: The OP asked it over at Anime too: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3815/49

Comment: @kevluv97: When you want your question to be asked on another SE site, you should flag it for moderator attention, and ask for it to be migrated, since cross-site posting is discouraged. You can also read [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-do-we-handle-conflicts-with-the-anime-and-movies-sites/627#627) and [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2901/6365) for more info, or help on how to choose between here and Anime. :)

Comment: This is not related to Hellsing, but rather to Hellsing Ultimate.  VERY different.

Answer (score 2):

Seras Victoria experiences repeated visions of [Baron Vladimir Harkonnen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Harkonnen) from the David Lynch film "Dune" claiming to be to be the spirit of her gun.

As far as I can tell, there's no [canon](http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/161/282/161282537_640.jpg) [sic] explanation for the reason why it chooses to manifest itself in this particular way, aside from the fact that her gun is actually called **The Harkonnen** (which is itself a contraction of the formal name of the gun; e.g.

- **H** ellsing **A** rms ***A*** nti-Midian ***C*** annon" becomes "HAA Cannon" becomes "[Harkonnen](http://hellsing.wikia.com/wiki/Harkonnen)").

[image: Seras Chased by Harkonnen]

Although she is initially scared by the Baron's 'spirit' and runs from it on several occasion, it does ultimately provide a successful (and **wholly accurate**) warning that she is being targeted by a Rio S.W.A.T. team which would seem to indicate that there's more to her visions than mere introspection brought on by extreme psychological pressure.